# Why my .submit() function in jquery dont work after show a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using the JQUERY library in version 3.6.0 and I'm making a form when the submit button is pressed, a modal is jumped that is held for 5 seconds and then makes the corresponding submit of the form,

The problem is when I press the submit button, the submit() inside the code does not work and enters an infinite loop showing the modal again without sending the data to where I am indicating it with POST, what could be the error or if I am skipping something?

This is the original code:

```html
<form action="../controller/CtrlCreaproyecto.php" method="post" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="test" id="test" required />
  <button type="submit" id="Send">Send</button>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```js
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e)
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  setTimeout(function() 
    {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $("#myform").submit();
    }
    , 5000);
  });
```

I have tried to change the jquery syntax as follows:

```js
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e)
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  setTimeout(function() 
    {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
    , 5000);
  return false;
  $("#myform").submit();
  });
```

But the only thing I got with this was that the modal did not react infinitely anymore, but without sending the data yet

Comment: no indentation... is no clarity ... :/

Comment: The problem is that your code simply triggers your own code again. You need to set and check some flag variable so the second time you exit the function instead of calling e.preventDefault() etc again

Comment: u need to do it this way $('#send').on('click', function(e){...................} , the problem is submit function call the submit again and again so the trigger should be on the button or u dont need to keep this part in your code $("#myform").submit();

Comment: You can also remove the submit event listener like `$('#myform').off('submit');` afaik

Comment: @mmh4all What? No.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you all for the comments and I really appreciate it, could you explain a little more how to apply the $('#myform').off('submit'); in the jquery function in question? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `$("#myform").submit();` -> `$("#myform")[0].submit();`  - you need to submit the form using the js (vanilla) .submit() not jquery's .submit().

Comment: Code after a `return` doesn't run - `return false; ..some other code` the "some other code" will never run.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the explanation brother, with the method of `$("#myform")[0].submit();` and before the return it has worked perfectly, thank you very much and blessings